# Opposite of <pre> tag

Tags: html, pre

I just want to know if there's an opposite tag for `<pre>`. Like when the elements are interpreted as plain text, I want the browser to interpret it as HTML tags.

For some reason, what I get is the plain text with the tags in it but the browser doesn't interpret it.

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know there is not an "opposite" of <pre>, but exactly what you need to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `opposite` of the `pre`. Somewhere, you are html-encoding the text with the html tags in it, causing them to become escaped, and thus, displayed as text, rather than interpreted as html.

You can html-decode the text to turn text-tags into html tags again.

Could you show us the code/software you're using to create the tags, or at least the language you are using so we can show you how to do it?

Comment: it's written on apex. it's just a simple {!variable}. It works on other parts tho. I'm on the front end side so I thought there might be something to workaround that.

Comment: so it's in a templating engine? Those will most definitely html-encode any input they get. Could you show us the contents of that variable?

Answer (score 0):

There is no opposite tag of `<pre>` but you can use JavaScript, and set the "HTML text" to the `innerHTML` property of some element.

For example:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var myHtmlText = "<strong>HaHaHa</strong>";
  document.getElementById("code-container").innerHTML = myHtmlText;
}
```

```html
<span>Hello! </span>
<span id="code-container"></span>
```

*note*: it's important to use it after the target element was rendered, using `window.onload`